# Type interference issue with the WebFlux WebTestClient and Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, type-inference, spring-webflux

I'm building a prototype for a new application using Spring Webflux and Kotlin. Spring Webflux contains a WebTestClient for unit tests. According to the documentation I should be able to test the results of a REST call like this:

```
@Test
fun getVersion_SingleResult_ContentTypeJson_StatusCodeOk_ContentEqualsVersion() {
    //given
    var version = Version("Test", "1.0")
    val handler = ApiHandler(version!!)
    val client = WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction(ApiRoutes(handler).apiRouter()).build()

    //expect
    val response = client.get().uri("/api/version/").exchange()
    response.expectStatus().isOk
    response.expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
    response.expectBody(Version::class.java).isEqualTo(version)
}
```

However, I'm running into some type interference issues. The problem is in the combination of 'expectBody' and 'isEqualTo'.

The error I get is:

> Kotlin: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun  isEqualTo(p0: Version!): T! Please specify it explicitly.

The used methods have the following signatures:

```
<B> WebTestClient.BodySpec<B, ?> expectBody(Class<B> var1);

public interface BodySpec<B, S extends WebTestClient.BodySpec<B, S>> {
    <T extends S> T isEqualTo(B var1);
}
```

Sadly I'm running into the limits of my knowledge of generics and the differences between Kotlin and Java which means that I'm not sure how I should specify this.

Edit: Like I said below, it compiles when I use `isEqualTo<Nothing>(version)`. However, this causes a NullPointerException when the isEqualTo ends without a failure. This seems to be because the 'isEqualTo' method returns a value, which is now defined as the 'Nothing' type.

Comment: Try response.expectBody(Version::class.java).isEqualTo<Version>(version)

Comment: I've tried this option, however, it leads to the following error: Kotlin: Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'Nothing!'

Comment: Try replacing Version with Any. response.expectBody(Version::class.java).isEqualTo<Any>(‌​version)

Comment: New update: It does compile if I use 'response.expectBoyd(Version::class.java).isEqualTo<Nothing>(version). This will be because the 'isEqualTo' method has a <T extends S> generic and S is definied as 'S extends WebTestClient.BodySpec<B, S>'. However, the result of this is a nullpointer even though the body is not null. Using isEqualTo<Any> also doesn't compile. It gives an error that it should be a subtype of Nothing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now fixed on Kotlin side, see [this blog post](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1530.html#improvements-to-type-inference-for-recursive-generic-types) for more details. Require a flag with Kotlin 1.5.30 and will be the default as of Kotlin 1.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.

Looks like the solution is to use an extension function `.expectBody<Version>()`

please refer to:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20251#issuecomment-453457296

so, you can change your code to:

```
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.expectBody
......
response<Version>.expectBody().isEqualTo(version)
```

it should work