# How to use Spring's WebTestClient to check for a string in Kotlin?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin, webtestclient

I am trying to use the WebTestClient to check a Controller that returns a string. But for some reason I get an error.

I use Kotlin so I tried to apply the Java examples I have found to it but I can't figure out how to do it right. What am I missing?

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class HelloResourceIT {

    @Test
    fun shouldReturnGreeting(@Autowired webClient: WebTestClient) {

        webClient.get()
                .uri("/hello/Foo")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk()
                .expectBody(String::class.java)
                .isEqualTo<Nothing>("Hello Foo!")
    }
}
```

When I try to use `String` or `java.lang.String` instead of `Nothing` I get the error message:

> Type argument is not within its bounds.
>   Expected: Nothing!
>   Found:String!

When I use `Nothing` I get a NPE.

There is already [Type interference issue with the WebFlux WebTestClient and Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295818/type-interference-issue-with-the-webflux-webtestclient-and-kotlin) but I works with a specific type. String does not seem to work here. What I am missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you are not using the extension function that was identified as a work-around. To use it, try updating the last two lines of your test as follows:

```
webClient.get()
    .uri("/hello/Foo")
    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    .exchange()
    .expectStatus()
    .isOk()
    .expectBody<String>()
    .isEqualTo("Hello Foo!")
```

which appears to work correctly.

For reference:

- [Type interference issue with the WebFlux WebTestClient and Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295818/type-interference-issue-with-the-webflux-webtestclient-and-kotlin)
- https://github.com/sdeleuze/webflux-kotlin-web-tests/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/com/example/ControllerWebFluxTest.kt

Comment: This works. I messed up the import thus my IDE was not providing me any information about it. Thank you!